# rails 3: hash attribute in a override to_xml model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, xml-serialization

I wrote a override for the to_xml model method and right now im trying to get a hash attribute to be transformed into a set if symbol => values pair but i had no success.

the result of the `intersected_categories` method is a hash like:

```
{:"1"=>["Broken Board", false], :"2"=>["Sticking", false], :"3"=>["Bottom tier missing", false], :"4"=>["Bad I/L", false], :"5"=>["Delamination", false], :"7"=>["Sheet level - smile", false], :"8"=>["Sheet level - frown", false], :"9"=>["Missing SS", false]}
```

The to_xml method

```
def to_xml (options={})
  xml = options[:builder] ||= Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent => options[:indent])
  xml.instruct! unless options[:skip_instruct]
  xml.wip @wip,
  :number => self.number,
  :start_time => self.wip_start_time,
  :end_time => self.wip_end_time,
  :line => self.system.name,
  :shift => self.shift,
  :crew => self.crewF,
  :sm_crew => self.crewSM,
  :sm_shift => self.shiftSM,
  :product => self.SMMainGroup, 
  :product_group => self.product_group, 
  :sheets => self.sheets,
  :interleavers => self.interleavers,
  :wip_grade => self.intersected_categories,
  :comment => self.comment
end
```

ive tried a couple of things with no success:

```
def to_xml (options={})
  xml = options[:builder] ||= Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent => options[:indent])
  xml.instruct! unless options[:skip_instruct]
  @wip.intersected_categories.each do |grade|
    wip_categories << {grade[1][0].to_sym => grade[0][1]}
  end
  .
  .
  :comment => self.comment,
  wip_categories #explodes
end

###### another try
  :interleavers => self.interleavers,
  :wip_grade => self.intersected_categories,
  :comment => self.comment,
  self.intersected_categories.each do |grade|
    << grade[1][0].to_sym => grade[0][1] #with / without {} it keeps failing
  end
end
```

Any idea how can i achieve what i need?

**Update**

Current xml:

```
 <wip number="123h11008" start_time="2014-05-13 09:21:00 -0500" end_time="" line="cl1" shift="1" crew="A" sm_crew="A" sm_shift="1" product="1111111" product_group="G2" sheets="0" interleavers="0" wip_grade="{:"2"=>["Bottom Tier Missing", false], :"3"=>["Falling", false], :"4"=>["Broken Boards", false], :"5"=>["Crown", false], :"6"=>["DIP", false], :"7"=>["Green Boards", false], :"8"=>["Delamination", false], :"9"=>["Bad I/L", false]}" comment=""/>
```

expected xml:

```
 <wip number="123h11008" start_time="2014-05-13 09:21:00 -0500" end_time="" line="cl1" shift="1" crew="A" sm_crew="A" sm_shift="1" product="1111111" product_group="G2" sheets="0" interleavers="0" Bottom Tier Missing=false Falling =  false Broken Boards = false Crown = false DIP = false Green Boards = false Delamination = false Bad I/L = false comment=""/>
```

Comment: Can you show what is expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
xml.wip @wip, {
 :number => self.number,
 :start_time => self.wip_start_time,
 :end_time => self.wip_end_time,
 :line => self.system.name,
 :shift => self.shift,
 :crew => self.crewF,
 :sm_crew => self.crewSM,
 :sm_shift => self.shiftSM,
 :product => self.SMMainGroup, 
 :product_group => self.product_group, 
 :sheets => self.sheets,
 :interleavers => self.interleavers,
 :comment => self.comment }.merge(Hash(self.intersected_categories.values))
```